# JavaScript - If Else

Tags: javascript

I have JavaScript code for some function with If Else statements. But it is too long. I need to make it easy. So the problem is, how to reduce the line of codes in the following function?

```
 function clickFunction(e) {

            if(document.getElementsByName('insert_data1')[0].value == 1 || document.getElementsByName('insert_data1')[0].value == 0){
                document.getElementsByName('inputvalue1')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByName('insert_data1')[0].value;
                }
                else{
                    alert("Please enter 0 or 1 !!"); 
                }
            if(document.getElementsByName('insert_data2')[0].value == 1 || document.getElementsByName('insert_data2')[0].value == 0){
                document.getElementsByName('inputvalue2')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByName('insert_data2')[0].value;
                }
                else{
                    alert("Please enter 0 or 1 !!"); 
                }
            if(document.getElementsByName('insert_data3')[0].value == 1 || document.getElementsByName('insert_data3')[0].value == 0){
                document.getElementsByName('inputvalue3')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByName('insert_data3')[0].value;
                }
                else{
                    alert("Please enter 0 or 1 !!"); 
                }
            if(document.getElementsByName('insert_data4')[0].value == 1 || document.getElementsByName('insert_data4')[0].value == 0){
                document.getElementsByName('inputvalue4')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByName('insert_data4')[0].value;
                }
                else{
                    alert("Please enter 0 or 1 !!"); 
                }

                e.preventDefault(); 
                return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not tested at all but perhaps something like this might do the trick?

```
function clickFunction(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputs=['inputvalue1','inputvalue2','inputvalue3','inputvalue4'];
    var fields=['insert_data1','insert_data2','insert_data3','insert_data4'];
        fields.forEach( function(e,i,a){
            var field=document.getElementsByName( e )[0];
            if( field.value==1 || field.value==0 ) document.getElementsByName( inputs[i] )[0].innerHTML=field.value;
            else alert("Please enter 0 or 1 !!");
        });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If it helps you might consider accepting the answer

Comment: If I need get two field.values separately and adding those two values and get the result value into document.getElementsByName( 'output' )[0]. Then how to change above code? could you please give some trick if you can . :)